# Flutter Firebase Messaging Not working on IOS when app running in background or closed

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have configured firebase Cloud Messaging with flutter Notification are working in foreground. but not working when running in background or app is killed.

Following steps are done.

- Generated app ID and push Key in
  https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/
- Added info.plist to ios/Runner folder
- Turned on Push capabilities
- Uploaded APNS certificate to Firebase console
- Added lines in AppDelegate.swift

Also tried to remove following line as suggested on [Flutter Firebase Cloud Messaging - Notification when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164702/flutter-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-when-app-in-background)  but it is still not working.

if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
  [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = (id) self;
 }

```
Flutter Doctor

[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-IN)

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices

    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.

      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.

      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.

      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.



[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web

[!] Android Studio (not installed)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

One thing I noticed that , when app is installed first time it is not asking me to check if the I allow the app to send push notification.

My code is having following lines on page after login page.

```
_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
```

Also cross checked that all following setting are ticked.

[image]

Comment: any update on this with new version release ?

Comment: I guessing you are using the local_notification with this package, it's a common issue conflict between local_notification and this package

Comment: I took a week, but the same nothing.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution?

Answer (score 18):

After a long time searching for a fix, this solved the problem for me:

1. In your info.plist:

   ```
    FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled: false
   ```
2. Add this to your AppDelegate:

   ```
   override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

      Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
      super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
    }
   ```

Comment: what you have added inside AppDelegate can you share your code?

Comment: Only this method, you just need to place it inside the AppDelegate class and import Firebase

Comment: Thank you @dcg your solution worked for me. This should been in the  firebase_messaging documentation.

Comment: What are the imports for the `AppDelegate` changes?

Comment: don't forget to add "import FirebaseMessaging" in AppDelegate

Comment: hello After add the code to appdelegate i cant run it on simulator.. is given error

Comment: There's already a function called application, should I copy the 2 lines inside the function body?

Comment: Exactly, just use it inside this function.

Comment: This must be marked as the right answer, thans so much. I spend hours trying to solve this, and is missing the AppDelegate.swift edition in the Google´s official documentation

Comment: please share your AppDelegate.swift whole code as it's not working on my side and giving the "Cannot find 'deviceToken' in scope"

Answer (score 13):

My Solution is as follows and it works.

publspec.yaml

> firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9

Remove following line from ios/runner/AppDelegate.m or ios/runner/AppDelegate.swift if used.

```swift
if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
  [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = (id<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>) self;
 }
```

in Dart code use provisional `false`, Should get pop up to confirm on notification.

```dart
myFirebaseMessagingService.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: false));
```

In Xcode Following Push notification along with background Fetch and remote notification.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that `Push Notifications & Background Mods` Capabilities were enabled in the `All` tab under `Signing & Capabilities`, not only in `Profile` like what I was doing.

[image]

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1041#issuecomment-612660797

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to change or add in AppDelegate and Info.plist, just provide the correct notification payload and it will trigger:

sample valid payload

```
{
  "to" : "my_fcm_token",
  "notification" : {
 "body" : "sample body",
 "OrganizationId":"2",
 "content_available" : true,
 "mutable_content": true,
 "priority" : "high",
 "subtitle":"sample sub-title",
 "Title":"hello"
 },
  "data" : {
    "msgBody" : "Body of your Notification",
    "msgTitle": "Title of your Notification",
    "msgId": "000001",
    "data" : "This is sample payloadData"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have similar issue, I need to revoke the old key, create a new authentication key and upload again to make it works:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs#create_the_authentication_key
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_authentication_key

Answer (score 2):

**After spending couple of days, finally i found a solution. Please follow the below steps carefully**

1. Add this line to your `info.plist` `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled : NO`

[image]

2. Add following code to the `AppDelegate`

[image: 2]

```
 func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

3. In order to activate background handling in iOS, the following fields need to be included to the notification request:

> `"content_available": true`

As a result, testing this functionality through the Firebase console is not possible. To achieve this, notifications must be sent using Postman.

4. Add the following parameters to the `headers` of the request

> `Content-Type` : `application/json`

> `Authorization`: `key = your_server_key`

[image]

5. Send notification though the Postman

[image]

request url :

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

request body :

```
{
  "to" : "your_fcm_token",
  "notification" : {
 "body" : "sample body",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 "Title":"hello"
 }
}
```

**This works for me !**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my app working and listening to onBackgroundMessage on Android (I just removed the notification object from my payload, leaving only the data object).

```
    final data = {
  "registration_ids": userToken,
  "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
  "priority": "high",
  "collapse_key": "type_a",
  "data": {
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "other_data": "any message",
    "title": 'NewTextTitle',
    "body": 'NewTextBody',
    "priority": "high",
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
  },
};
```

Comment: The question is to make it work on IOS. not android, therefore this answer is invalid

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it as below.

Complete the tutorial guide and try the following:

- Edit : iOS/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist

  - `<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key> <string>{bundleIdentifier}.flutter</string>`
  - {bundleIdentifier} is:
    Enter the Bundle name set at https://developer.apple.com.
- Example

  - Developer.apple: com.example.app
  - xcode BundleIdentifier : com.example.app
  - iOS/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist : com.example.app.flutter
- Test environment :

  - Firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  - Firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
- (Additional) When sending from your server or page

  - Please set the "notification" item.

Comment: which tutorial? Can you please complete it ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case `Team ID` from apple developer account in Firebase Project settings  for iOS app was incorrect